# Pandas Top N% of values within each group while ignoring missing values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, nan

I have a df and I want, for each line (which correspond to a month), to have a list of 50% of the highest values of "B" in that line.

| month | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-07 | A | 50 |
| 1994-07 | B | 60 |
| 1994-07 | C | 70 |
| 1994-07 | D | 80 |
| 1994-07 | E | NAN |
| 1994-07 | F | NAN |
| 1994-08 | A | 90 |
| 1994-08 | B | 60 |
| 1994-08 | C | 70 |
| 1994-08 | D | 95 |
| 1994-08 | E | 100 |
| 1994-08 | F | 110 |
| 1994-08 | G | NAN |

For July/1994 I only have 4 columns "B" filled with values, so 50% will be the 2 highest MV. For the month after, I have 6 stocks, which gives me 3 highest values:

| month | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1994-07 | C | 70 |
| 1994-07 | D | 80 |
| 1994-08 | D | 95 |
| 1994-08 | E | 100 |
| 1994-08 | F | 110 |

I have tried:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).apply(lambda g: g.nsmallest(len(g)//2, 'B'))
```

However, it does not ignore "NAN" and count it as a number. For example, for July/1994 it counts 6  values, and so it returns me the 3 (50% of 6) the highest values from the month. Instead, it should count that there are 4 values and return me the 2 highest.

Comment: Is `df["column"].count()` useful?

Comment: It does not work for me because I have to group by date, so I cannot simply count everything in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to use `g['B'].count()` as `count` ignores NaNs:

```
(df
 .groupby('month')
 .apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(g['B'].count()//2, columns='B'))
 .droplevel(0).sort_index()
)
```

Alternatively, `dropna` first:

```
(df
 .dropna(subset='B')
 .groupby('month')
 .apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(len(g)//2, 'B'))
 .droplevel(0).sort_index()
)
```

output:

```
      month  A      B
2   1994-07  C   70.0
3   1994-07  D   80.0
9   1994-08  D   95.0
10  1994-08  E  100.0
11  1994-08  F  110.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could pass `median` to `groupby.transform`, then filter values greater than the median (i.e. top 50%). Since `median` method skips NaN by default, no issues there.

```
out = df[df['B'] > df.groupby('month')['B'].transform('median')]
```

Output:

```
      month  A      B
2   1994-07  C   70.0
3   1994-07  D   80.0
9   1994-08  D   95.0
10  1994-08  E  100.0
11  1994-08  F  110.0
```